why ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.opflow' occured?
i installed version 1.1 of qiskit. i don't have any idea why i can't able to use opflow module.
this is the line i have error from qiskit.opflow import Gradient, StateFn, CircuitStateFn, Z
and this error occured in google colab:
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1eb6f7fd39a6> in <cell line: 11>()
      9 from qiskit.circuit import ParameterVector
     10 from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
---> 11 from qiskit.opflow import Gradient, StateFn, CircuitStateFn, Z
     12 from qiskit_machine_learning.neural_networks import OpflowQNN
     13 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.opflow'

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.


i expect to be able to use opflow module after installing qiskit 1.1
and the document of qiskit is not tell anything about it.

qiskit.opflow was deprecated sometime before qiskit 0.44. The functions and classes were migrated to other modules. Here is the list of opflow functions and where were they moved:



opflow
Alternative




qiskit.opflow.gradients
qiskit.algorithms.gradients


qiskit.opflow.state_fns.StateFn
In most cases, qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector


qiskit.opflow.state_fns.CircuitStateFn
qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector


qiskit.opflow.Z
qiskit.quantum_info.Pauli





The functions and classes were migrated to other modules.

Opflow was deprecated and subsequently removed in Qiskit 1.0 - the code was not migrated to other modules. There are alternatives that can be considered for some of the functionality, where more detail is available in this opflow migration guide which includes code samples of how it was done in opflow and how to do similar where an alternative exists.
